# Regestring NSRULProtocol for NSURLSessions Globally

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlsession, nsurlprotocol

I am trying to use NSURLProtocol to handle authentication challenges for every NSURLSession connection . I used

```
  [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[CustomHTTPSProtocol class]]
```

for NSURLConnection .But it is not working with NSURLSession so i need to set`SessionConfiguration.protocolClasses=@[[CustomHTTPSProtocol class]];`.
The problem is i use this URLProtocol class to only handle authentication challenges and i get received data's in the delegates of original class.

Something like this

**OriginalClass**

NSURLConnection

```
 -(void)sendURL
 {
   [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[CustomHTTPSProtocol class]];  //done globally in didFinishLaunching
    self.URL =[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.co.in"]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:self.URL];
 self.connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
   NSlog(@"received data...%@",data);
  }
```

NSURLSession

```
-(void)sendURL
 {
    self.URL =[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.co.in"]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:self.URL];
  sessionConfiguration =[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  sessionConfiguration.protocolClasses=@[[CustomHTTPSProtocol class]];
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
   NSURLSessionDataTask*task=  [session dataTaskWithRequest:checkInInfoRequest];
    [task resume];
   }

   - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
  {
 NSLog(@"data ...%@  ",data); //handle data here
  }
```

**NSURLProtocol Class**

NSURLConnection

```
-(void)startLoading
 {
   NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
[NSURLProtocol setProperty:@YES forKey:CustomHTTPSProtocolHandledKey inRequest:newRequest];

  self.connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:newRequest delegate:self];

 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{

if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}
else
{
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

}
```

NSURLSession

```
 - (void) startLoading {

NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
[NSURLProtocol setProperty:@YES forKey:CustomHTTPSProtocolHandledKey inRequest:newRequest];

NSURLSession*session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
self.sessionTask=[session dataTaskWithRequest:newRequest];
[self.sessionTask resume];
 }

 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{

if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
   }
 }
```

Using the above logic i was able to handle authentication for all request globally and handling response individually. But with NSURLSession if i use NSURLProtocol, authentication is done in Protocol class but i am not able to receive data, since my original class delegates are not called.

Somebody help me out.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement making the request yourself (or resend it as you did), your protocol becomes the challenge sender.  You are responsible for creating an **NSURLAuthenticationChallenge** object, setting yourself as the sender, providing all the other bits from the existing challenge, and sending it using the **NSURLProtocolClient** class.

Take a look at Apple's [CustomHTTPProtocol Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Listings/Read_Me_About_CustomHTTPProtocol_txt.html) project for examples and further information.